# Import declarations may only appear at top level of a module and trying type="module" just gives me a new error

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working with fairly simple code. I'm making a todo list and using webpack because I'm following The Odin Project. I have my index.js in my src folder where I create the UI elements. I have another js file, projects.js  where you can actually add new projects. I want to import the add project function so when you click on the +project button you can add a new project. But whenever I try to import on either js files I have, it gives me the "" error. I googled, some people said to add type="module" to the scripts I'm using. So I did that and now I get an error in the firefox console when I open my html:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resources at file: todo-list/src/index.js (Reason: CORS request not http)" and "Modules source URI is now allowed in this document todo-list/src/index.js"

I'm not advanced enough to understand what this means even after googling these errors. I literally just made another project, and had 0 issues importing things from other js files. I'm very confused. Can anyone help me? ):

my import looks like this:

```
import addProject from '.projects.js'
```

Comment: You can try your html using server and localhost, e.g. using [python](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) or [nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:webpack]. This can bundle your modules into a single browser friendly file. Browsers also support modules natively. The errors you are getting are related to using modules natively. So are you using webpack or not? If you're using webpage, then you need to provide an [mcve], which would include your configuration at the very least.

Comment: @MelF. I agree with JanStránsky. It might be because you're creating your webpage purely with local files. Try putting it on a server.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out - for both errors, when I was following the webpack tutorial here (https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) I forgot to create the webpack.config.js file. I started from scratch, and made sure I used this first command, which I skipped on accident when I first started the project:

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Also, me being dumb, and not remembering how things worked with webpack as described in TOP, I don't need to actually add the `<script>` tags for all the scripts I'm using besides the main.js (the stuff that looks like spaghetti code) since I'm guessing it knows what to do with the index.js and goes from there, as index.js is referenced as the `entry:` in the webpack.config.js file.

I'm fairly new at working with webpack, so hopefully that makes some sense if someone else comes across this issue like me. I had to go back and look at my restaurant page project and see how it was set up. (^: